# Translucent polyurethane gradient material node setup

Tags: rendering

Trying to recreate this gradient of cast polyurethane pieces in blender. Each of the x10 pieces is its own colour along the gradient. My limited knowledge has kept me in the principled shader unfortunately.

Rough colour codes...

#1 - E9C64C

#2 - DFB243

#3 - D49E3B

#4 - C78B35

#5 - BA792F

#6 - AB672A

#7 - 9C5625

#8 - 8C4621

#9 - 7B361C

#10 - 6A2717

[image]

Comment: Are they all of the same thickness? It doesn't seem so, so I'd say that you should maybe take a look at the volume shaders as well

Comment: Hello :). How close did you get? Show your current result and node setup :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect all colors are the same, but what changes is the transparency and maybe the roughness. That is the data that would be useful to reproduce the material accurately.

In any case, the basic setup n cycles would be a glass shader, where you can control the roughness and a combination of volume absorption, for the color, and volume scatter for translucency.

[image]

Hex codes for color are not very useful, as they are meant for sRGB display referred images displayed on a monitor, and blender does not work that way. The same color can look very different depending on the lights and surrounding elements.